# Sending UTF-8 string to managed bean does not work

Tags: jsf, utf-8, character-encoding, glassfish

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" >
    <head>
    </head>

    <h:form>
        <h:body>
            <h:inputText value="#{editorBean.value2}" />
            <h:commandButton action="content.xhtml" value="Submit" />
        </h:body>
    </h:form>
</html>
```

- value 2 is a String in a sessionscoped ManageBean
- using JSF Mojarra 2.1.19
- Glassfish 3.1.2

When I enter `äüö` and submit the form, it appears as `Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼` in stdout.

But if I use ajax, then this does not happen.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

JSF/Facelets uses by itself already by default UTF-8 throughout the process.

You only need to tell Glassfish that the request parameters are encoded using UTF-8, so that it will properly decode it using UTF-8. Open the `/WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml` file and add the following entry to the `<glassfish-web-app>`:

```xml
<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
```

By the way, your `<h:form>` has to go *inside* the `<h:body>`, not outside. Also, you should be using `<h:head>` instead of `<head>` in order to get JSF to auto-include the proper Ajax scripts.

Comment: quite strange.. other projects working fine in same server!

Thanks a lot!